# explicit the x-value for plotting in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, bar-chart

In GNUPLOT, I would like to plot 5 values on a single bar chart, separated with some spacing in between. If I have data formatted as such:

> 3342336, 3375103, 7110653, 32770, 0

where those 5 values are the y-values, how can I specify the x-values myself for where they should belong?

For example, I would like my bar chart to have each entry be of length 1,
so I plot y-value 3342336 at x-value 1,
y-value 3375103 at x-value 3,
y-value 7110653 at x-value 5,
y-value 32770 at x-value 7,
and y-value 0 at x-value 9.

I would appreciate any example code that can achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Is the data supposed to be in multiple rows, or is it really formatted as one comma separated row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in one row as shown, you can achieve this by using the *plot for* syntax looping over the column index, and calculating the x value from that index.  We can grab the column by using the *column* function which retrieves the specified column number.

```
set boxwidth 1
set datafile separator comma    # only if data is comma separated
plot for [i=1:5] (2*i-1):(column(i)) with boxes
```

If we need to ensure the same line type is used each time, we can explicitly state it in the plot command.

```
plot for [i=1:5] (2*i-1):(column(i)) with boxes lt 1
```

[image]

Additionally, if a key is to be generated, and we don't wish each plot statement to generate one, we can test for and only give a nonempty title on the first iteration (an empty title is treated the same as no title).

```
plot for [i=1:5] (2*i-1):(column(i)) with boxes lt 1 title (i==1)?"Title":""
```

---

If your data is separated into rows as is the normal format, this can be obtained a different way.

Gnuplot has several pseuduocolumns (see `help pseudocolumns` for details).  In your case, column 0 is of interest.  Column 0 gives the line number of the data starting at 0.  Thus to get sequential odd numbers like that, you can use `2*$0+1`.

For example, if your data (stored in **datafile.txt**) looks like

```
3342336
3375103
7110653
32770
0
```

and you wish to plot boxes of length 1 at those values, you can do

```
set boxwidth 1
plot "datafile.txt" u (2*$0+1):1 with boxes
```

Comment: What if my the data is in columns as follows:
> 3342336  3375103  7110653  32770  0
Such that I cannot reorganize it in my original data file to all fit into one column. Is there a simple way to tell gnuplot to read each column with the (2*$0+1):1 formula?